# Showing a set of limit points of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have been wrestling with this question and I am not sure how to solve it.

**Question:**

Let $(X, s)$ be a measure space and $\{f_n\}$ a sequence of measurable functions such that $f_n:X\to R$ with the normal Borel sigma algebra on $R$.

Let $$A = \{x\in X | \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)\text{ exists}\}$$

Show $A$ is measurable.

..

I know we need to show $A$ is in s but I don't know how, we don't have integrals yet so this needs to be proved only using facts about measurable functions.

Help would be greatly appreciated.( I saw another post on this but it did not help)

Comment: Hint: $$A(n,m,k) = \left\{ x : \lvert f_n(x) - f_m(x)\rvert \leqslant \frac{1}{k}\right\}$$ is measurable for all $n,m,k$.

Comment: I don't think integrals would help here to be honest.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is complete so it suffices to consider Cauchy sequences, and the difference of measurable functions is measurable.

Answer (score 9):

Hint : Show that $\liminf f_n$ is measurable. The proof for $\limsup f_n$ is similar, and 
$$
\{ x \in X \, | \, \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n \text{ exists} \} = \{ x \in X \, | \, \liminf_{n\to \infty} f_n = \limsup_{n\to \infty} f_n\}.
$$
Hope that helps,

Comment: But lim sup f_n is not measurable as it may not be finite....

Comment: @Mathstudent : You can either work with $\pm \infty$ in your $\sigma$-algebra for $\mathbb R$ or take the subset of points where it is finite. (It is less of a problem as in the limit case, because at least the $\limsup$ is always defined, just sometimes taking the $\infty$/$-\infty$ value.)